# jquery : focus to div is not working

Tags: jquery

After the ajax function is over. in success messages I'm focusing to the specific div. But it's not working. My code is here.

```
$j.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
    type:"POST",
    data:"action=press_release&page="+0+"&do_task="+do_task+"&id="+id+"&module="+module,
    success:function(data){
        $j("#com_cont").show();
        $j("#com_cont").html(data);
        $j("#loading_heart").hide();
        $j("#focus_point").focus();
    }
});
```

This is the code is not working(Not focusing on the div:`$j("#focus_point").focus();`

Comment: what exactly is the content of this div?

Comment: the best answer is on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery

Answer (score 83, accepted):

you can use the below code to bring focus to a div, in this example the page scrolls to the `<div id="navigation">`

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#navigation').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Comment: My main problem with this is: onFocus() listeners elsewhere in your application will not be made aware of change.  Besides that, it's actually a clever solution.

Comment: i wanted to focus, but you are scrolling.

Answer (score 133):

a `<div>` can be focused if it has a `tabindex` attribute. *(the value can be set to -1)*

For example:

```
$("#focus_point").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

---

**In addition**, consider setting `outline: none !important;` so it displayed without a focus rectangle.

```
var element = $("#focus_point");
element.css('outline', 'none !important')
       .attr("tabindex", -1)
       .focus();
```

Comment: This is what i've seen as well but I can't get it working for Ie8 or Ie7

Comment: I can't seem to get this working for Ie8 or Ie7 either I've also seen that you need to add setTimeout so it gives the event some extra time

Comment: +1 Definitely the correct answer in terms of actual focus, try tabbing one the accepted answer and focus returns to the beginning, this one starts on the focus point.

Comment: Make sure that $j("#focus_point") isn't an element that users with accessibility needs would need to tab to. Setting tabindex to -1 will make it untabbable, and removing the tab outline would make it so the user wouldn't see the outline when tabbed to.

Answer (score 22):

Focus doesn't work on divs by default.  But, according to this, you can make it work:

> The focus event is sent to an element
>   when it gains focus. This event is
>   implicitly applicable to a limited set
>   of elements, such as form elements
>   (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links
>   (`<a href>`). In recent browser
>   versions, the event can be extended to
>   include all element types by
>   explicitly setting the element's
>   tabindex property. An element can gain
>   focus via keyboard commands, such as
>   the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the
>   element.

http://api.jquery.com/focus/