# Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div on my page:

```
<div id='div1' style='overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;max-height:200px;'></div>
```

How can I make the div scroll to the bottom of the div?? Not the page, just the DIV.

Answer (score 707, accepted):

The other solutions here don't actually work for divs with lots of content -- it "maxes out" scrolling down to the height of the div (instead of the height of the *content* of the div).  So they'll work, unless you have more than double the div's height in content inside of it.

Here is the correct version:

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

or jQuery 1.6+ version:

```
var d = $('#div1');
d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Or animated:

```
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: $('#div1').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
```

Comment: This also works: $('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1').attr("scrollHeight"));

Comment: How to make this work without setting an absolute height (in px) to `div1`?

Comment: Well done! I was looking for a snippet to scroll and all I could find it page scrolling (html, body). This is a great solution and using scrollHeight is a great way to make sure it always reaches the bottom.

Comment: amazing, the second one it works like so: `d = $('#div1'); $(d).scrollTop( $(d).prop("scrollHeight") );`

Comment: Is there anyway to stop auto-scrolling when user holding scroll?

Comment: `$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);`  works

Answer (score 74):

All the answers that I can see here, including the currently "accepted" one, is actually wrong in that they set:

```
scrollTop = scrollHeight
```

Whereas the correct approach is to set:

```
scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight
```

In other words:

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight - $('#div1')[0].clientHeight);
```

Or animated:

```
$("#div1").animate({
  scrollTop: $('#div1')[0].scrollHeight - $('#div1')[0].clientHeight
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I have a div with a set height and overflow set to auto. The animated answers worked but this is the only non-animated solution that would actually scroll to the bottom of the "content", not the set height of the div. Bravo!

Answer (score 27):

UPDATE : see [Mike Todd's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551414/1065525) for a complete answer.

---

```
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: $('#div1').height()}, 1000);
```

if you want it to be animated (over 1000 milliseconds).

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1').height())
```

if you want it instantaneous.

Comment: Wrong! .height() is limited to displayed area, .prop("scrollHeight") is real height of div.

Comment: Absolutely! That's why Mike Todd's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551414/1065525) is the accepted one, not mine.

Answer (score 15):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
```

This grabs the height of the page and scrolls it down once the window has loaded. Change the `1000` to whatever you need to do it faster/slower once the page is ready.

Comment: This scrolls the whole page right? I just want the div to scroll to the bottom of the div.

Comment: touche. same logic, different selector.

Answer (score 12):

None of these worked for me, I have a message system inside a web app that's similar to Facebook messenger and wanted the messages to appear at the bottom of a div.

This worked a treat, basic Javascript.

```
window.onload=function () {
     var objDiv = document.getElementById("MyDivElement");
     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't have jQuery installed.  You're working with native dom, they're using jQuery. https://jquery.com/

Comment: Very neat and elegant solution.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
$('#div1').scrollTop( $('#div1').height() )
```

Answer (score 6):

The following will work. Please note `[0]` and `scrollHeight`

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myDiv")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Scroll window to the bottom of target div.

```
function scrollToBottom(id){
  div_height = $("#"+id).height();
  div_offset = $("#"+id).offset().top;
  window_height = $(window).height();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: div_offset-window_height+div_height
  },'slow');
}

scrollToBottom('call_div_id');
```

Answer (score 5):

for animate in jquery (version > 2.0)

```
var d = $('#div1');
d.animate({ scrollTop: d.prop('scrollHeight') }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in a legacy codebase trying to migrate to Vue.

In my specific situation (scrollable div wrapped in a bootstrap modal), a v-if showed new content, which I wanted the page to scroll down to. In order to get this behaviour to work, I had to wait for vue to finish re-rendering, and then use jQuery to scroll to the bottom of the modal.

So...

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
    $('#thing')[0].scrollTop = $('#thing')[0].scrollHeight;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check scrollHeight and clientHeight with scrollTop to scroll to bottom of div like code below.

```js
$('#div').scroll(function (event) {
  if ((parseInt($('#div')[0].scrollHeight) - parseInt(this.clientHeight)) == parseInt($('#div').scrollTop())) 
  {
    console.log("this is scroll bottom of div");
  }
  
});
```

Comment: always please test your code before providing the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let width = $(window).width();
    let element = $("#YourId");
    let positionFromTop = element.offset().top + element.prop("scrollHeight");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: Math.abs($(window).height() - positionFromTop)
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply scroll to the bottom of a div, then just use an huge out of range integer, no css or height reference is needed.

`$("#ScrollabledDiv").scrollTop(200000)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to scroll to bottom of div on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').scrollTop($('div').scrollHeight);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

When page is load then scroll is max value .

This is message box when user send message then always show latest chat in down so that scroll value is always is maxium.

```
$('#message').scrollTop($('#message')[0].scrollHeight);
```

[see image](http://prntscr.com/r3v53p)