# Scroll to bottom of a <div> with jQuery on page load (multiple <div>)

Tags: jquery

I know this has been answered here [Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery), but this solution is not working, when having more than one  `<div>` with different heights.

```
$('.myContent').scrollTop($('.myContent')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Is not working with multiple `<div>` with different heights!

See http://jsfiddle.net/4pfLQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.myContent').each(function () {
    $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pfLQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

With this code - `$('.myContent').scrollTop($('.myContent')[0].scrollHeight);`  you are only targeting the first div of DOM tree having class `myContent` due to the inclusion of `[0]` in the code.

Comment: You should mention that ALL `<div>`s are being scrolled the the scroll height of the first `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide, which of DIVs you want to scroll. You can select one of them

```
$(".myContent:eq(N)")
```

where N - is a number of the DIV, counts from 0.
Or if you want to scroll every DIV, then try it:

```
$('.myContent').each(function () {
    $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
});
```