# JQuery scrollTo Bottom of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo jQuery plugin in order to auto-scroll to a specific part of the page. When clicking the button on the page (#neo_scroll_button), I want the page to scroll the length of the div #neo_home_panel.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h9kw9/

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
<div id="neo_wrapper">
    <div id="neo_home_panel">   <!-- Start panel 1 -->
        <div id="neo_scroll_button">
            <p>Enter</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>  <!-- End of panel 1 -->
    <div id="neo_content_panel">    <!-- Start panel 2 -->
        <div class="neo_img_container">
            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=450&h=250&bg=0ff&fg=000000" />
        </div>
        <div class="neo_text_container">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="neo_text_container">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="neo_img_container">
            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=450&h=250&bg=0ff&fg=000000" />
        </div>
        <div class="neo_img_container">
            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=450&h=250&bg=0ff&fg=000000" />
        </div>
        <div class="neo_text_container">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="neo_img_container2">
            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=960&h=250&bg=0ff&fg=000000" />
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- End panel 2 -->
</div>  <!-- End of wrapper -->
```

SASS:

```
 body, html { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#neo_wrapper {  /* Wrapper for entire page */
width: 100%;
height: 1045px;
margin: 0 auto;

#neo_home_panel {   /* Opening panel */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #999999; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/

    #neo_scroll_button {    /* Div that enables scroll */
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 25px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
        height: 35px;
        background: #F00;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 35px;
        display: table; /* Allows text to be completely centered */
        cursor: pointer;

        a { /* Formatting for link */
            &:link {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
            &:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;}
        }
    }
}

#neo_content_panel {    /* Content panel (images/text) */
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #CCC;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/

    .neo_img_container {    /* Container for images */
        float: left;
        width: 450px;
        height: 250px;
        /*margin-right: 25px;*/
        &:nth-child(odd){
            margin: 0 60px 15px 0; 
        }
    }

    .neo_text_container {   /* Container for text */
        float: left;
        width: 450px;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        &:nth-child(odd){
            margin: 0 60px 15px 0; 
        }
    }

    .neo_img_container2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
}
```

And JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $homePanelHeight = parseInt($('#neo_home_panel').height());

$('#neo_scroll_button').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo('$homePanelHeight', 800);
    //alert("Hello world");
});

 });
```

Comment: Awesome, looks like I had the right idea. For some reason looking at the API I thought variables needed to be in quotes. Still learning!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634170/scroll-to-bottom-of-a-div-with-jquery-on-page-load-multiple-div?lq=1

Comment: Somehow the comment I got that answered my question got deleted, how should I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of anchor tag we can easily achieve like this [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9kw9/8/).

Here I what I added in `neo_scroll_button`

```
 <a href="#end"> <div id="neo_scroll_button"><p>Enter</p> </a>
```

And at the end of `neo_content_panel` :

```
 <dev id="end"></div>
```

Also, In JS :

```
$(function() {
  $('a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```