# Anchor Tags - Link to bottom of browser window instead of top

Tags: html, css, browser, web, anchor

http://jsfiddle.net/Sy269/3/

In the example below, by clicking a 'Bottom of Section' link, the browser window will link to that anchor using the top of the browser window. In other words, if you click Bottom of Section 2, Section 2 will not be visible until you scroll up a notch.

Is there any way to use the bottom of the browser window/JSFiddle window to anchor to the Section 2 tag (correctly displaying Section 2 at the bottom of the screen with everything else above it)?

```
<div id="section1" class="section1">  

Section 1

<div id="bottom1"></div>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="section2">  

Section 2

<div id="bottom2"></div>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="section3">  

Section 3

<div id="bottom3"></div>
</div>

<div id="section4" class="section4">  

Section 4

<div id="bottom4"></div>
</div>

<a href="#section1">Go to Section 1</a>

<a href="#section2">Go to Section 2</a>

<a href="#section3">Go to Section 3</a>

<a href="#section4">Go to Section 4</a>

<br />

<a href="#bottom1">Bottom of Section 1</a>

<a href="#bottom2">Bottom of Section 2</a>

<a href="#bottom3">Bottom of Section 3</a>

<a href="#bottom4">Bottom of Section 4</a>
```

I have this jQuery code all ready in place:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        jQuerytarget = jQuery(target);
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': jQuerytarget.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript.  Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Sy269/2/

The issue is that anchors are made to go to the top. So, if we take the window height.

`Anchor Location+$(window).height()`

So after some code modification:

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

See: [Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

use anchor before div like : `<a id="#section1"></a>` it will jump to that div