# One-Page Layout Scroll Up

Tags: html, scroll, web

I don't know how am I going to explain this one, I am building a one-page layout website but instead of the 'usual' scroll down effect, I want something like this: 
www.xsbaltimore.com

You have to scroll up in order to see the other sections, but I am wondering how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice way to do it to make sure people see the page has content by scrolling up would be to animate it.

```
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: $('#div1')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

This would scroll the page over 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

But lots more information over here... [Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .scrollTop() to set the scroll position to the bottom when the page loads.  See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/).

As a side note, having users scroll up is not intuitive, so just keep that in mind when you are doing your usability testing.  Make sure that it is obvious enough that they need to scroll up.