# How to have the overflow hidden of 'top' of html content not 'bottom'

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div with the following css

CSS

```
#divToUpdate {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and I am sending it new html content from jquery.

JS (jquery)

```
$("#divToUpdate").append(newInfo);
```

But i want the 'focus' of the div to be on the new content, not on the historically first content.

Comment: you mean you want to use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and add the content on top of the existing?

Comment: No, because the html should be read 'storylike' at a later point (top to bottom)

Comment: @Nico, but thanks because I had forgotten about prepend and maybe it could be used if all else fails, THANKS!

Comment: Then you should have a look at [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery). You can add content to your container and scroll to the end of it to "hide" the previous content.

Comment: OK, off to have a look, thx again. Surprised that i'll have to use js though!

Comment: The solutions there are not suitable for me given the amount of html content in relation to html div size.

Answer (score 0):

try : `$(this).focus()`

maybe it helps

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what "focus" means.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe 'focus' is for form ELEMENTS.