# How to make append div text visible without scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for the low quality question...

i'm working on chat bot project, Searched lot and coded lot. All works except append html div place below the input tag.. each time scroll up to see the last message. All i need is last message stays visible. Please see the image for more detail

[image]

Ok... This is my code..

```
<div class="chat-flow">
    <div class="cloudchatreverse">
        <div>
            <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
                <p class="text-right">How do you do ?</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cloudchat">
        <div>
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p>Hey I'm fine thanks... Can you able to login with twitter</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="post_message" name="message" placeholder="What's up" autofocus required>
```

and the style

```
.chat-flow {    /* scroll bar */
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

if you need anything i can provide right way...

Update:

This is for when submit and append from client side

```
$(function(){
    document.onkeydown=function(evt){
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if(keyCode == 13)
        {
            var post_message = document.getElementById("post_message").value;
            $(".cloudchat").append('<div class="cloud"><blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">'+ post_message +'</blockquote></div>');
            var request = {};
            request.post_message = post_message;
            //your function call here
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{% url 'post_message' %}",
                    data: JSON.stringify(request),
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    success: function(result){
                        document.getElementById('post_message').value='';
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: please provide the jquery too

Comment: You need to scroll to bottom after appending. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery)

Comment: @anpsmn do you think `scrollTop` is what i looking for ???

Comment: @Rosine, showing some error in console, can you please correct that, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @stanze I updated with full code ...

Comment: @Rosini yes, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aha0hfeo/)

Comment: @anpsmn Your animate method do the tricks. Can you make answer here so i can give correct mark

Comment: I updated my code please have a look at it

Comment: @Rosini Its ok. I got the answer from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551414/473016). You can accept the answer below too or upvote there on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it scrolls to bottom

```js
    $(document).keydown(function (evt) {

        if (evt.which == 13) {
            var post_message = $("#post_message").val();
            $(".cloudchat").append('<div class="cloud"><blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">' + post_message + '</blockquote></div>');
            
            var scroll=$('.cloudchat').height();
            $('.chat-flow').animate({
                scrollTop:scroll
            },200)
        }
    })
```

```css
.chat-flow {
    /* scroll bar */
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-flow">
    <div class="cloudchatreverse">
        <div>
            <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
                <p class="text-right">How do you do ?</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cloudchat">
        <div>
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p>Hey I'm fine thanks... Can you able to login with twitter</p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="post_message" name="message" placeholder="What's up" autofocus required>
```