# Chat text auto scroll down and information load from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to be able to keep chat text to be always scrolled to the bottom of the chat.

I have looked at many tutorials and tried many examples from stack overflow but none of them worked.

Currently my chat text keeps on going out of the `textarea` when there is too many lines, even so i have `overflow:hidden`.

I also want the textarea to only load last 50 entries from the database so that when users join they will not have to load everything that is said in the chat.

Any Idea how to do those 2 things?

home

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <div id="Holder">
        <div id="Header"></div>
   <link href="../Style/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Chat Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e){
                //When we press Enter do
                if(e.keyCode==13){
                   var ChatText =  $("#ChatText").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'InsertMessage.php',
                        data:{ChatText:ChatText},
                        success:function(){
                            $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
                            $("#ChatText").val("");
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            setInterval(function(){//refreshes every 1500ms
                $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");
            },1500);
            $("#ChatMessages").load("DisplayMessages.php");

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome <span style="color: green"><?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] ; ?></span> </h2>
</br></br>

<div id="ChatBig">
    <div id="ChatMessages">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="ChatText" name="ChatText"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Css

```
#ChatBig {
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;

}
#ChatMessages{
    width: 100%;
    height: 548px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
}
#ChatText{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
}
#ChatText:focus{outline: none;}

body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
#Holder {
    width: 100%;
}
.UserNameS{
    color: #7CB9E8;
}
.UserNameS:hover{text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;}
```

Image of how the site looks

http://gyazo.com/fe71d7d9699b9784fda5ba1c862fad53

Comment: From your picture there might be a few issues. To help you with the scrolling issue, here are suggested solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery

Comment: um.. after i tried using the code from tutorial my code doesnt load anything from database even when i remove the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have a scroll, perhaps you can use `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;`, just like in this example

```css
#ChatBig {
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#ChatMessages{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 498px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
}
#ChatText{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#ChatText:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<div id="ChatBig">
    <div id="ChatMessages">
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        asd<br/>
        qwe<br/>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="ChatText" name="ChatText">
</div>
```

you need to make the `container` to `position: relative;`, then make the child to `absolute`.

first, the `ChatBig` is `600px` and `ChatText` is 50px, so change the `ChatMessages` to

```
min-height: 498px; // don't use height
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px; // because ChatText is 50px
```

then for the `ChatText`, set it to

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

and there, you will have the latest `ChatMessages` keep at the bottom

**Note**: The qwe is only to identify the last line

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `max-height` property.

```
.class
{
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I dont want a scoll bar.. as i dont want people to scroll up when the chat moves it moves

Answer (score 0):

What does this line mean

```
<input type="text" id="ChatText" name="ChatText"></textarea>
```

wither it should be

```
<textarea id="ChatText" name="ChatText"></textarea>
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="ChatText" name="ChatText"/>
```