# Default scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm building a chat application in which I need the scrollbar to be at the bottom of the chat window (last message) on page load.

How do I accomplish this (Using jQuery or otherwise)?

Here's the chat window div:

```
<div id="ccwindow">

      <div class="bubble me">Hey!</div>
      <div class="bubble you">Hello</div>
      <div class="bubble me">I saw your post. Want to buy the book. Are you an XYZ University?</div>
      <div class="bubble you">Yes, sophomore year.</div>
      <div class="bubble me">Great!</div>
      <div class="bubble you">I'll buy it. Can you get it to school tomorrow?</div>
      <div class="bubble me">Sure. See you tomorrow!</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery)

Comment: @Sagar I think he wants to reposition the scroll bar, not scrolling to the bottom

Comment: @chris97ong i understood that he needs the position of the scroll bar to be at the bottom of the page on page load from this line "I need the scrollbar to be at the bottom of the chat window on page load". pl correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/vtep7Lf1/

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#ccwindow").animate({ scrollTop: $("#ccwindow").height() }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#ccwindow").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, 1000);
});
```

**Note:**

Using the `.load` rather than `.ready` will take images into account.