# How to scroll to automatically scroll to the bottom of an editable div onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I get an editable div to remember the position of the scroll bar? Im currently programming a Chrome extension and have a notepad style editable div which users can write notes in. I have the code listed below currently which autofocuses the div onload and displays the caret at the end of the text within the div.

I now just need my scroll bar to scroll level with the caret if its further down the div.

```
    var div = document.getElementById("edit_notepad");

div.onfocus = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(div);
            range.collapse(false);
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(div);
            range.collapse(false);
            range.select();
        }
    }, 1);
};

div.focus();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the different approaches done in [Scroll to bottom of Div on page load (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery) and choose which best suits your concern.

One suggested solution is to scroll down to the height of the div as suggested by [@Mike Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551414/6092067)

> Correct version:
>
> `$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);`

This related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some simple `localStorage`?

```
var position = localStorage.position || 0;
div.scrollTop = position;
localStorage.setItem("position", div.scrollTop);
```

The code above should get and set the position of the div scroll amount, as far as I know.