# jquery: how to scroll a div by n pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Using jQuery, how do you scroll a div by N more pixels?

So far I tried

```
$("div.foo").scrollTop(75);   //scroll down by 75 pixels
```

Comment: Please share the css for you div.foo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the jQuery docs for scrollTop:

> Description: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for
>   the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical
>   position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

The version of the function you are calling sets the vertical position of the scroll bar *from the top of the element*, not from the current position. So in order to scroll down from the current position you first have to retrieve your current position. There are a few ways to do that, but you could do something like:

```
var $foo = $("div.foo");
$foo.scrollTop($foo.scrollTop() + 75); // scroll 75px down from current
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for **Vanilla JavaScript solution** like I was, here it is.

```
const selectedElement = document.querySelector('div.foo');
selectedElement.scrollTop = 75;
```

querySelector [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector),
scrollTop [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Answer (score 1):

the following code may help and you may see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery) .
and you can pixel value from window atrributes.Thank you.

```
var d = $('#div1');
d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
```