# Scroll to the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Is there a way I could scroll to the bottom of a div when the page loads ?
I've already tried multiple things but they didn't work.

Please help if you know the answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Comment: You can find the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503606/scroll-to-bottom-of-div-on-page-load-jquery

Comment: @SidharthSoni His question is different as he wants it to make it scroll on page load

Comment: What you tried can you show here?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#1').scrollTop($('#1')[0].scrollHeight);                                            
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `body` tag apply this event trigger `onload="myFunction()"`. Add `<a id="bottom"></a>` to the bottom of your div.

**JS:**

```
    function myFunction()
{
  location.replace("pagename#bottom");
}
```

Comment: @FantasmoClone27 Do comment if any problems arise with my logic.

Comment: it's not working for me since I'm using Django