# jquery focus does not trigger css focus

Tags: jquery, css

There seems to be a problem when setting focus to an element using jquery. It apparently does not trigger the :focus css property set on an element.

For example in my css I have:

```
div.item1:focus { border:2px solid red; }
```

in my jquery I have:

```
$("div.item1").focus();
```

The focus is set but there is no red border applied to the element.

Answer (score 10):

`div` elements do not use the `:focus` selector .. see [the CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

> The :focus pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus (accepts keyboard events or other forms of text input).

You could do this:

```
.hoverclass { border:2px solid red; }

$("div.item").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hoverclass')
},function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hoverclass')
});
```

This uses [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 4):

`focus()` is only usable with form elements and links, and wont work if you try to use it on other types of elements.

See the [jQuery doc for focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) for more information,

Comment: In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. -- from jQuery docs link above

Comment: Seems kind of sketchy to use as there is no definition of what a "recent browser" is, but it can be done that way as well of course. Other worksarounds is probably preferable.

Comment: I just found ppk's work on this, he has included 'elements with tabindex' for his search it looks

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966034/1013082

Answer (score 0):

Go to jQuery focus() page to see :

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

Go to PPK's study of focus on browsers here

[PPK focus Event Browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html)

It looks like all browsers pass the tabindex test.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this:

```
$("div.item1").focus(function(){
        $("div.item1").css("border","2px solid red");
      });
```

Comment: how about outline instead of border?