# How can i scroll to an element in a scrollable div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the `onClick` function.

How can I use `onClick` to scroll to an element or id of a div in a scrollable div using Jquery?

An example of how to do this would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: Can you research > try something > if it doesn't work ask us ?

Comment: http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: This answer might help you (credit to user "derek"):

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5966034/2161375

Answer (score 0):

You can used this:

```
$("element").click(function() {
    $('div').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

But if you want some advice specifically have to give an example