# focusin is not supported in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

`focusin` doesn't work in Google Chrome and Firefox. It works in IE. What should I use here to make it works in all browsers?

Here debugger isn't fired in Chrome and Firefox. Works in IE.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    // the column fields should match the excel columns
    columns: [
        { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Sub" },
    ],
    dataSource: [
        { Name: "Ram", Sub: "Math" }
    ],
}).on('focusin', function(e) {
    debugger
    //something here
});
```

Comment: Try using `focus` event http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: ya tried with focus. but not working..

Comment: Can make some JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wapipapi/1/edit

Comment: I don't think that `div` has focus event. Only input fields.

Comment: But its working in IE

Comment: Now that i have inspected your JSBin code, i see that in my FF textarea is created on focus, but it has `opacity: 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : focus to div is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965924/jquery-focus-to-div-is-not-working)

Comment: Thank you @Justinas. I placed below code, end of my script. Now its working in all browsers. used the blur and focus instead of focusout and focusin. $("#focus_point").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();

Answer (score 0):

It seems Firefox does not support the focusint event, and chrome has incomplete support.

[source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html)

Comment: used the blur and focus instead of focusout and   focusin. but not working.