# How would I use javascript or jquery to "focus" on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By focus, I don't just mean scroll to that section of the page. Is there a way to make the browser behave as if the user had clicked on that `div`? The use case here is that I want a user to be able to scroll in a div using the `arrow keys`, but the `div` appears on the click of another button which does not click the `div` itself, so attempting to scroll with the `arrow keys` does nothing since the main page is not `scrollable` and is `"focused"` by default. Obviously the `.focus` function does not work on divs so I am wondering how to do this!

- This is NOT the same question as the one that it was marked as a duplicate of. There are links to similar questions in the answers to this one but currently this is marked as a duplicate of the wrong question

Comment: Your note that it's not a duplicate is incorrect as you've accepted an answer that is literally a copy of an answer in that question (even with a link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add a `tabindex` attribute with value of `-1` to the `<div>` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965924/jquery-focus-to-div-is-not-working/11928222#11928222) and it will work with the below code:

```
$('div').attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
```

Comment: Instead of copying the exact code from some other answer, it would be much better to VTC as duplicate.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, what's VTC?

Comment: - Vote to close

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, right - I'm < 3k rep - don't know much about it. Thanks for clarification

Comment: This worked great, thank you. What is the tabindex attribute for?

Comment: For focusing on the div correctly. It's complex.